Android Emulator Freezing with "Emulator is Not Responding" on Ubuntu 22.04

I am facing an issue where my Android Emulator consistently becomes unresponsive, displaying the "Emulator is not responding" message every few seconds. Clicking either "Wait" or "Force Quit" does not resolve the problem, and the emulator freezes almost immediately after it starts.
System information:

Model: Lenovo IdeaPad 3 15IIL05
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.5
Processor: Intel Core i3-1005G1 CPU @ 1.20GHz × 4
RAM Size: 20 GB
Disk: 500 GB (NVMe SSD)
Graphics: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (ICL GT1)

I've tried:

Increasing the emulator's RAM and VM heap size.
Disabling hardware graphics acceleration (running in software mode).
Cleaning and rebuilding my Android project.
Updating all Android SDK tools to the latest versions.
Ensuring that KVM virtualization is enabled.


It could be because of Wayland. You can try X11 to see if it persist
